# Select Where in script

Tags: php, mysql, html-lists

I have a script that selects Events according to the day, however I want to implement a condition that I select according to a column I created called user.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Event;
use MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Facades\Calendar;
class EventController extends Controller
{
       public function index()
            {
                $events = [];
                $data = Event::all();
                if($data->count()) {
                    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                        $events[] = Calendar::event(
                            $value->title,
                            true,
                            new \DateTime($value->start_date),
                            new \DateTime($value->end_date.' +1 day'),
                            null,
                            // Add color and link on event
                         [
                             'color' => '#ff0000',
                             'url' => 'pass here url and any route',
                         ]
                        );
                    }
                }
                $calendar = Calendar::addEvents($events);
                return view('home', compact('calendar'));
            }
}
```

I have checked that I should use Event: find () instead of Event :: all () but it is returning error.

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Was there a *question*  ?

Comment: I want to put a where within this condition so that it selects according to a column user.

Comment: I have checked that I should use Event: find () instead of Event :: all () but it is returning error.

Comment: What is the error?